# SQL SUM statements returning different results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, crosstab

Can somebody explain why the two select statement results below are different!
I know the first statement is correct (using CASE) but I can't understand why the second statement is wrong.

```
CREATE TABLE #sales
(
YearSold int,
Quarter char(2),
Amount money
)
GO

INSERT INTO #sales (YearSold, Quarter, Amount) values (2003, 'Q1', 1)
INSERT INTO #sales (YearSold, Quarter, Amount) values (2003, 'Q2', 2)
INSERT INTO #sales (YearSold, Quarter, Amount) values (2003, 'Q3', 3)
INSERT INTO #sales (YearSold, Quarter, Amount) values (2003, 'Q4', 4)
INSERT INTO #sales (YearSold, Quarter, Amount) values (2004, 'Q1', 5)
INSERT INTO #sales (YearSold, Quarter, Amount) values (2004, 'Q2', 6)
INSERT INTO #sales (YearSold, Quarter, Amount) values (2004, 'Q3', 7)
INSERT INTO #sales (YearSold, Quarter, Amount) values (2004, 'Q4', 8)
INSERT INTO #sales (YearSold, Quarter, Amount) values (2005, 'Q1', 9)
INSERT INTO #sales (YearSold, Quarter, Amount) values (2005, 'Q2', 10)
INSERT INTO #sales (YearSold, Quarter, Amount) values (2005, 'Q3', 0)
INSERT INTO #sales (YearSold, Quarter, Amount) values (2005, 'Q4', 0)

GO

SELECT YearSold,
 SUM(CASE Quarter WHEN 'Q1' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Q1,
 SUM(CASE Quarter WHEN 'Q2' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Q2,
 SUM(CASE Quarter WHEN 'Q3' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Q3,
 SUM(CASE Quarter WHEN 'Q4' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Q4
FROM #sales
GROUP BY YearSold

SELECT t.YearSold, SUM(a.Amount) AS Q1, SUM(b.Amount) AS Q2, SUM(c.Amount) AS Q3, SUM(d.Amount) AS Q4
FROM #sales t
LEFT JOIN #sales a ON t.YearSold = a.YearSold AND a.Quarter='Q1'
LEFT JOIN (select * from #sales where Quarter='Q2') b ON t.YearSold = b.YearSold 
LEFT JOIN (select * from #sales where Quarter='Q3') c ON t.YearSold = c.YearSold 
LEFT JOIN (select * from #sales where Quarter='Q4') d ON t.YearSold = d.YearSold
GROUP BY t.YearSold

--select * from  #sales

DROP TABLE #sales
```

**Note**: Using SQL Server 2008 Express

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `left join` returns every matching row in the right-hand table for each row in the left-hand table.

To see what happens, remove the `group by` from your second query.

```
SELECT *
FROM #sales t
LEFT JOIN #sales a ON t.YearSold = a.YearSold AND a.Quarter='Q1'
LEFT JOIN (select * from #sales where Quarter='Q2') b ON t.YearSold = b.YearSold 
LEFT JOIN (select * from #sales where Quarter='Q3') c ON t.YearSold = c.YearSold 
LEFT JOIN (select * from #sales where Quarter='Q4') d ON t.YearSold = d.YearSold
```

You'll see there are four rows for each year.  That's because `from #sales` will give you four rows for each year.  The end result is that the `group by` counts everything four times.